# Django: Is it possible to achieve the same thing as sql's exists?

Tags: python, django

To make my question more understandable, here's an example.

There are two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

So in this example, A and B are of one-to-many relationship. Now let's say I'd like to make the following query: find an A that has at least one B as child. In sql, clearly I should use exists clause. Is it possible to achieve exactly the same with orm?

I've done some research on that but can't find a perfect match to the sql query. The closest solution is like:

```
A.objects.filter(b__pk__gt = 0).distinct()
```

But it's still far from the exists clause in sql and might not be as efficient as exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will select all `A`s that have one or more associated `B`s:

```
A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False)
```

Switching it to `b__isnull=True` will select only `A`s that have no `B`s associated with them.

Comment: So with b__isnull=False, I no longer need to append distinct any more? And it's a bona fide exists clause in sql?

Comment: You don't need distinct, but I'm not sure what query it executes exactly. It is however, the best you're going to do with the Django ORM. Otherwise, just directly use the SQL you want with `raw`.

Comment: Get the right answer before you go out of your way to optimize.  If you really must look under the covers at the ORM's SQL try: `import django; django.db.connection.queries` from `./manage.py shell`.

Comment: I had a try and notice that distinct is not necessary with this simple query. But let's say I now want to do a query like "find an A that has at least one B with name Test as child", then I have to write it as A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False, b__name = 'Test').distinct(). So in all, it can achieve the same thing as exists clause, but it's still far from a real exists clause.

Comment: You don't need `b_isnull=False` there, and distinct is really not the best way to get an `A` in that scenario. Instead, you should use: `a = A.objects.filter(b__name='Test')[0]`. Or, if you simply just want to test if it exists (without retrieving the object), use: `A.objects.filter(b__name='Test').exists()`

Comment: I don't get it, I have the same issue. I have a Model P and another mother C with the P foreign key. If I query P.objects.filter(c__isnull = False) I got the error that c is not a valid option. c is not a P field. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually (if I am not misunderstood what you are trying to do) with plain sql a simple left join would be the way to go instead of the EXISTING clause.

Your queryset works just fine without the .distinct()

I recomend you to have a look at the queries that django orm generates, so that you can see what's going on and actually run ANALYZE/EXPLAIN instead of guessing the performances.

You can see the raw query from the query attribute of a queryset or, even better, install the django debug toolbar and see all the queries for a given request.

Comment: +1 for the debug toolbar.  If you do look at the query, you will probably find that `A.objects.exclude(b__isnull=True)` performs a LEFT OUTTER JOIN and `...filter(b__isnull=False)` performs an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @istruble indeed, join is the way to go for this kind of query

Comment: Sorry. But I have to disagree with you on your exists vs simple left join comment here. My example is simply looking for an A that has a B child. I have no filter on B. So exists or its replacement are natural choices.

Comment: @GeorgiePorgie hard to say which one performs better, thats why I suggest you to look at explain output if you really care about the performances of that query. In terms of logic if you dont need to use the data from table b then you are right, exists fits better (even if the end result is comparable) :)